# pick_event in Jupyter with matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I really like the simplicity with how ipywidgets.interactive works with pandas dataframe but I am having trouble getting data when a point in a scatter plot is selected.

I have looked at some examples that use matplotlib.widgets etc. but none that use it with interactive in Jupyter. It looks like this technique would be described here but it comes up just short:

http://minrk-ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html

Here is an ipynb of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
from ipywidgets import interactive
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
from matplotlib.text import Annotation
from io import StringIO

data_ssv = """tone_amp_0  tone_freq_0     SNR
75.303        628.0  68.374
84.902       8000.0  61.292
92.856        288.0  70.545
70.000       2093.0  35.036
76.511       6834.0  66.952 """

data = pd.read_table(StringIO(data_ssv), sep="\s+", header=0)

col_names=list(data.columns.values)
plottable_col=( ['tone_amp_0', 'tone_freq_0', 'SNR'] )

def annotate(axis, text, x, y):
    text_annotation = Annotation(text, xy=(x, y), xycoords='data')
    axis.add_artist(text_annotation)

def onpick(event):
    ind = event.ind
    label_pos_x = event.mouseevent.xdata
    label_pos_y = event.mouseevent.ydata
    offset = 0   # just in case two dots are very close, this offset will help the labels not appear one on top of each other

    for i in ind:  # if the dots are to close one to another, a list of dots clicked is returned by the matplotlib library
        label = "gen_labels" # generated_labels[i]
        print( "index", i, label )    # step 4: log it for debugging purposes
        ax=plt.gca()
        annotate(ax,label,label_pos_x + offset,label_pos_y + offset)
        ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
        offset += 0.01 # alter the offset just in case there are more than one dots affected by the click


def update_plot(X='tone_amp_0', Y='tone_frq_0', Z='SNR'):
    plt.scatter(  data.loc[:, [X]],data.loc[:, [Y]], marker='.', edgecolors='none', c=data.loc[:,[Z]], picker=True, cmap='RdYlGn' )
    plt.title(X+' vs '+Y); plt.xlabel(X); plt.ylabel(Y); plt.colorbar().set_label(Z, labelpad=+1)
    plt.grid(); plt.show()

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

interactive(update_plot, X=plottable_col, Y=plottable_col, Z=plottable_col)
```

When I select a data point nothing is happening. Not sure how to debug this or understand what I am doing wrong. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Which backend are you using? I think the above should work fine in `%matplotlib notebook`, `%matplotlib nbagg` or `%matplotlib widgets`.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The above is the entire notebook. When I start Jupyter it states "Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel". The interactive is imported from ipywidgets. Are you saying I need to add the line '%matplotlib widgets'?

Comment: What does `plt.get_backend()` print? Yes, if you haven't set any backend, it may well be that you are not using any of the mentionned ones.

Comment: I tried %matplotlib notebook at one point and it did not work and it was still not working, however %matplotlib nbagg seems to be working okay. Is there a good reference for the discussion of these backends and which one I should be using?

Comment: To be honest, I always thought those were the same, just with a different name. Are you sure there really is a difference? (Always start with a fresh kernel when testing such things.) As for a discussion of jupyter/IPython backends, I do not know any good overview. But those notions might help you find relevant information when searching.

Comment: so if I do not explicitly define the backend and I run plt.get_backend() I get module://ipykernal.pylab.backend_inline

Comment: Yes, so matplotlib events cannot work with the `inline` backend, simply because this produces png figures and you cannot interact with images.

Answer (score -2):

Try put a semicolon at the end of `plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)`.

Comment: It makes it so Jupyter doesn't render the returned value of that statement